# What is the better way to update latest data into SSRS report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I am having a few reports from multiple data tables (same database). Yesterday I tried to replace my same name database with the latest data. So I renamed existing Database and restored the latest database from the Production server to Development server.

Set the actual name as Development server was using previously. Then I have re-executed SSAS Cubes and dimensions (confirmed execution connection on the same server). But when I tried to refresh the SSRS reports on the screen all the data cell/values are showing `'0'` or `NULL` in all the fields.

Is there something that I have missed to get the latest data into the reports? Or is my way of doing this not the actual way to update latest data onto reports?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just restore over the current database? What's the purpose of renaming the *old* copy of the data?

Comment: @scsimon: For just the safety purpose I have done so. In case of any problem I can rename the old database so.

Comment: Don’t do that. Just take a backup of the old one before you restore over it. This will keep the database_id and underlying metadata the same and almost surely fix your problems.

Comment: @scsimon: Thanks for the advice, I just tried same way and successfully executed all the Cubes and dimensions still same problem in reports.

Comment: Because you have restored over the wrong database I suspect.  You need to restore over the original

Comment: @scsimon: Still same Issue! Currently I have removed earlier restored database from the server and confirmed the connection/name with older one, is it really matter if I am renaming the databases?